# CABasicAnimation duration & keeping layer position

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

I'm trying to make very basic animation for `UIButton`. The goal is rotate layer 180 degrees. Here is my animation code which is called from `beginTrackingWithTouch`:

```
private func rotateButton() {
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: "easeIn")
    rotationAnimation.toValue = M_PI
    rotationAnimation.duration = CollapseButton.kCollapseButtonAnimationDuration
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = true
    layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
}
```

Now I'd like to add collapsing view animation when tapping this button. In my VC:

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[UIView animateWithDuration:CollapseButton.kCollapseButtonAnimationDuration animations:^{

    CGRect currentFrame = weakSelf.frame;
    currentFrame.size.height = 20;
    weakSelf.frame = currentFrame;

}];
```

I have 2 questions:

1. After button finishes its animation it resets layer position. So, if arrow were showing top, it animated to showing down and finally resets to top. How can I preserve layer orientation?
2. As you can see animation duration and timing functions are the same. For the reason I cannot understand UIView animates much slower. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core animation is strange. The animation creates a "presentation layer" that generates the appearance of the change you are animating, but does not actually change the property in question.

In order to get your animation to finish with the object at the end state, you should set both a fromValue (at the starting setting) and a toValue, and then set the property to it's ending value after submitting the animation:

```
private func rotateButton() {
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: "easeIn")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0 //<<--- NEW CODE
    rotationAnimation.toValue = M_PI
    rotationAnimation.duration = CollapseButton.kCollapseButtonAnimationDuration
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = true
    layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    layer.transform = CATransformMakeRotation(M_PI) //<<--- NEW CODE
}
```

You can also set the animation's `removeWhenFinished` property to true, but that has other complications.

BTW, you should not try to manipulate the frame of a view that has a non-identity transform. Instead, set the scale on the view's transform.

I'm not sure why the 2 animations are taking different amounts of time. I do notice that you are setting the CAAnimation's timing function to `easeIn`, but leaving the UIView's timing function as the default (ease-in, ease-out.) That will create animations that don't look the same. You should probably set your view animation to use `easeIn` timing as well. (To do that you'll need to use the longer form `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`)

Comment: You saved my life. I was struggling with a glitch in CATransaction completion block. This fixed it!

Comment: @FrancescoLeoni, what was the glitch, and which part of my answer helped you? Maybe you should post a question that describes the problem you were having, and then post a self-answer? That would both provide a documented problem and solution for others, and give you a chance to earn some more reputation.